# How can I change windows security settings using python? i.e. Password Requirements / Require Ctrl - Alt - Delete to log in

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am writing code in Python 2 or 3 to script Cybersecurity functions.  Functions such as Lockout Duration, Password Length, and other things that involve a lot of clicking that could easily be automated.

```
import subprocess
subproccess.call(x, shell = True)
```

I plan on using that format to run (or enter ((so I don't have to type only press the answer button))) commands in command prompt (with Administrator privileges). However, I have no idea how I should do this, especially the "Require Ctrl - Alt - Delete on Startup." Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As of now I thought of a possible solution to the password requirement part of my problem that I will investigate, but am still totally lost on the ctrl - alt - delete part. :D

Comment: Policies ≠ Cyber Security.

Comment: @KlausD. Are you saying that Cybersecurity can't be discussed?  If that is the case this topic isn't just related to cybersecurity, it is related to broader topics as well :D.  I can take out the Cybersecurity word. :)

Comment: @KlausD. I have seen the severity of criticism on other posts.  I tried to answer a question and by the time I had typed the answer it was closed due to a breach of rules.  I would just like help, so I could change the wording or anything you see fit if it would allow me to get help :).                                        I am new to the community, so I would love help navigating ;).

Comment: There's a specific StackExchange for security related Q&A.  If you don't get much love here, perhaps post there: https://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Nick Thank you :D.  I appreciate the help and I will post it there aswell.

Comment: @Nick Worked Very Well, thank you :).

Comment: Excellent. :)  Care to link to the answer in comment here?  Just in case someone googlestumbles upon this page in the future..